# How to read text in kivy textinput or Label

Tags: python, kivy

imports:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
```

```
kv = '''
BoxLayout:
    text: your_textinput
    orientation: 'vertical'

    TextInput:
        id: your_textinput
    Button:
        text: 'click'
        on_press: app.clicked()

'''
```

`MyApp` class:

```
class MyApp(App):
    text = StringProperty('-.text')

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    def clicked(self):
        file = open('read.text', 'r')
        f = file.readlines()
        newList = []
        for line in f:
            newList.append(line.strip())
        print(newList)
        self.root.ids.your_textinput.text = (newList)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when I run the code I get this message  ( text = text.replace(u'\r\n', u'\n')
 AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like `id: your_textinput` in the TextInput kv, and `self.root.ids.your_text_input.text = newList` in the `clicked` method. Also see http://inclem.net/2019/06/20/kivy/widget_interactions_between_python_and_kv/ for other ways of passing references around.

Comment: Then post the new code and explain how it's failing

Comment: i don't know how to paste cod in comment